# Error When trying to pip install

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Adam/anaconda/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I get this error when i try to do pip install keras.
my bashprofile looks like this (using anaconda)

```
Chrome
export BROWSER
#sbt
export PATH=/opt/scala/sbt:$PATH
#xgboost
export PYTHONPATH=~/xgboost/python-package

#MAVEN
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/bin:$PATH

# added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/Adam/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Are you inside a virtualenv? if not, I would recommend it.  The error is related to a failed installation of setuptools, which is installed automatically by a virtualenv

Comment: no I am using anaconda

Comment: conda install -c anaconda setuptools=27.2.0 was what solved it thx